# new listing photo files not uploading in admin

Tags: php

I login in to my admin panel and upload a new listing. The listing gets approved.., added with the detail text, but the photos do not upload.

This is the 2 errors shown, just before the new listing get approved.

> Warning: copy(/www/resimler//_0_1411502150.jpg) (function.copy): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/webcont/public_html/admin/modulles/proses.php on line 210
>
> Warning: chmod( ) (function.copy): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/webcont/public_html/admin/modulles/proses.php on line 211

I have tried to see if there is a code error but not seeing.

Comment: Warning: copy(/www/resimler//_0_1411502150.jpg) Noticing a double slash "//" in the file path. That obviously is causing a problem.

Comment: i wonder how to locate a double // in a search perhaps dreamweaver mx

Comment: It doesn't nessesarily have to be inside your code. It could be that the code is something like $filePath = "/www/resimler/" and the part that adds your images automaticly adds a "/" in front of the name. But without having access to your code, I can't be sure about this.

Comment: Feel free to click on my name here and contact me via email (listed on profile). It's to much for me to explain to you in a comment and not acceptable as an answer to your question either.

Comment: i have sent you an email with thks.

Comment: You should have an answer. To prevent this turning into a chat, I'll further communicate through email only.

Comment: Great answers and this has now fixed the problem after inserting code at top. 

<? error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE|E_WARNING));